# One-To-Many Hibernate Entity Mapping : ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I am a `new bee in Hibernate` and I am using `PostgreSQL 9.3, JDK 1.7, Hibernate 4.0.2`

I am trying to save a `Customer` who `Has-a` relationship with `Address` i.e., `One-To-Many` Relation.

[image: Data-Base Mappings]

While saving the `Customer` i am getting the Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.cust.entities.Address
```

**Customer Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CustomerIdSeq", sequenceName = "c_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CustomerIdSeq")
    @Column (name="c_id")
    private Long cId;

    @Column(name="cname")
    private String cname;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Address
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="c_id")
    private List<Address> address;

    //getters and setters

    }
```

**Address Entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="address")
    public class Address {

        @Id
        @Column(name="c_id")
        private Long cId;

        @ManyToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="c_id")
        private Customer customer; 

        @Column(name="street")
        private String street;

        @Column (name="city")
        private String city;

        //getters and setters
      public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
           this.customer= customer;
           this.cId= customer.getCId();
       }

        }
```

I had tried some thing which is similar to [Java Persistence/Identity & Sequencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_ManyToOne_id_annotation)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Address record doesn't have an ID when calling `save()`.

You're missing the `@GeneratedValue` tag in that class, and if not specified, it defaults to "assigned" value.

If you're not assigning a value to `Address.cId` before calling `save()`, you'll see this problem. Post all relevant code if this isn't the cause of the issue.

EDIT: Looking at your table structure, Address should really have it's own ID in the schema design, and have a foreign key(FK) reference to `Customer.ID`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). For now consider the design as it is defined above, Can't the Address Entity use the Same Key that is used by Customer. I know that the design is not a good practice yet

Comment: Don't we have any @annotations to achieve this sort of One-To-Many Relation between Customer and Address

Comment: Without Address having it's own ID, there's little point using hibernate (I'm not even sure it's possible at all). Since Hibernate uses each object's ID to locate it in cache etc.

Comment: Then how come we can do that in One-To-One Mapping as [It is here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_OneToOne_id_annotation) Is it some restricted functionality in `Has-a` Relation. Guide me if i am thinking in a wrong way

Comment: Phone has an OwnerID, Address has an OwnerID, PhonePK has a "type" ID, and from what I can see of all the example code at that link, all ID variables are assigned before save() is called. Your problem is that you're trying to use an assigned ID, without assigning a value before calling save(). Check out the very bottom of your link for ideas where Address doesn't have a PK (generate the ID at runtime).

Comment: I had updated the setter in the Address Entity, but still the Exception stays in there. I am clear with the exception that i need to set it before saving it :P. I want to handle this scenario in Hibernate.

Comment: Post full code of the implementation. My bet is that customer.getCId() returns null at the point it is called.

Comment: "Without Address having it's own ID, there's little point using hibernate (I'm not even sure it's possible at all)." An object having no persistent identity of its own can be mapped an as embeddable.

Comment: "Can't the Address Entity use the Same Key that is used by Customer." How will that work when a customer can have > 1 address? "Don't we have any @annotations to achieve this sort of One-To-Many Relation between Customer and Address". Yes see answer suggesting '@Embeddable'.

Answer (score 0):

Form the comments to the previous answer and from your existing table structure, you may want to consider mapping Address as an Embeddable rather than as an Entity:

> This is similar to a OneToMany, except the target object is an
>   Embeddable instead of an Entity. This allows collections of simple
>   objects to be easily defined, without requiring the simple objects to
>   define an Id or ManyToOne inverse mapping. ElementCollection can also
>   override the mappings, or table for their collection, so you can have
>   multiple entities reference the same Embeddable class, but have each
>   store their dependent objects in a separate table.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

The mappings would then be as follows. Address will have no persistent identity of its own and can only exist as part of an Entity - currently customer but no reason you cannot use it with other entities requiring an address.

Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CustomerIdSeq", sequenceName = "c_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CustomerIdSeq")
    @Column (name="c_id")
    private Long cId;

    @Column(name="cname")
    private String cname;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "customer_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Address:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column (name="city")
    private String city;
}
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for. I will try this and update you back. Thanks for the Response :)

Comment: @AlanHay may you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?